# EACCES (Permission denied). Trying to access a file created by another application Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to read a file created by another Android application.

```
    File file = new File("/data/data/air.br.com.screencorp.MobilePlayer/br.com.screencorp.MobilePlayer/Local Store/token");
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        Log.d("SIZE", "Total file size to read (in bytes) : "
                + fis.available());

        int content;
        StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();

        while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
            token.append((char) content);
        }

        Log.d("TOKEN", token.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null)
                fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I don't know why, but I'm not allowed to access that file. I have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission on my manifest.

Should I use `SharedPreferences`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Data of other applications private data can not be accessed from your app. This is the security model of android. The app should have set `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` permission on the file, only then can you access the file

Comment: So should I use the `SharedPreferences` to exchange data from applications?

Comment: I dont think sharedpreferences is the right way to exchange data. you need to use either providers, intents and external storage depending on your requirement